# If $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite matrices with $A>B$, must $A^k > B^k$ for $k>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite matrices. If $A>B$, can we conclude that $A^k > B^k$ for any positive scalar $k$?

Note that $A>B$ means $A-B$ is a positive-definite matrix, not an element-wise comparison. I've tried using [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) but could not get anywhere with it so far.

Comment: A condition where this is true: $A$ and $B$ commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, take $B=I$ and

$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & -2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{array} \right) $$

$A$ is positive-definite since

$$ (\begin{array}{cc} x & y \end{array})
 \left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & -2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right) = 2 x^2 + 2 y^2 $$

$A-B$ is positive-definite since

$$ (\begin{array}{cc} x & y \end{array})
 \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right) = x^2 + y^2 $$

But

$$ A^2-B^2 = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -8 \\ 8 & 0 \end{array} \right) - I
= \left( \begin{array}{cc} -1 & -8 \\ 8 & -1 \end{array} \right) $$

and

$$ (\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \end{array})
 \left( \begin{array}{cc} -1 & -8 \\ 8 & -1 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) = -1 < 0$$

Comment: Thank you! Although it is not always a true statement, as you showed by this counterexample, I think it is true for some values of k (like k = 1/2 in the example you used). Do you know any proof for that case?

Comment: I think there are counterexamples for every $k \neq 1$.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this counterexample relies crucially on the fact that $A$, while positive-definite (i.e., $v^\dagger A v> 0$ for all vectors $v$), is *not* Hermitian? The Wikipedia article on the term suggests that some authors define positive-definite matrices to be Hermitian. This prompts the question of whether $A^k > B^k$ necessarily holds if $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite *and* Hermitian *and* $A>B$.

Comment: @JessRiedel Yes. In thinking it up, I considered $A$ in terms of a singular value decomposition and attempting to rotate from a direction where $|Av|/|v|$ is relatively small onto a direction where $|Av|/|v|$ is relatively large, so that $|A^2 v|/|v| < (|Av|/|v|)^2$ But a Hermitian matrix has no "rotational" part. Probably there's a simple proof I haven't seen from the fact that a Hermitian positive-definite matrix has singular decomposition $U^\dagger \Sigma U$ for $U$ orthonormal and $\Sigma$ diagonal with positive real values.

Comment: @aschepler, I found a Hermitian counterexample. I would have posted it as a separate answer, but this question has (unjustly, imo) been closed so it won't allow me. Therefore I have submitted it as a suggested edit to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have voted to reject as it should be a separate answer as you say; this is not the correct use of suggested edits. If aschepler wants to use your suggested edit, it can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1597159). If you want to reopen the post, you can make your case [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today). You could also post the question yourself (but do try to include something in the question to avoid it being closed)

Comment: Thanks Calvin for keeping the suggested edit easily accessible. fwiw, as a non-power user, I was not able to find a way to petition to reopen a post; I think that should be linked in the blue "question closed" header. Also, there is no easy way to find the reasons for closure. It just says the question does not meet the (long list of) guidelines. Pretty frustrating.

Comment: Oh jeez, this complicated procedure for petitioning to re-open isn't worth it. What a waste of time this all is. I did the actual work, produced a useful counterexample, and even typed it up nice, but I'm not going to argue with a bunch of mods and worry about violating the reopen queue timeline guidelines or whatever. I wish I had never bothered.